# How can I change the WindowTitle of the Read-Host prompt in the PowerShell ISE?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I know how to change the title of the main ISE window using something like

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "My Awesome New Window Title"
```

but I'm wondering how to get access to the title of the window that pops upon a Read-Host request like:

```
$strP4Pass = Read-Host "Please enter Perforce Password" -assecurestring
```

It pops with `Windows PowerShell ISE - Input` as the title - and yes, I know I have my `Please enter Perforce Password` prompt *within* the window - but I'd really like to be able to customize the title - any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a custom prompt with multiple choices using System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription

```
$Yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "Yes Please"
$No = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "No, Thank you"
$YesNoChoices = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($No,$Yes)
$Answer = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice("Caption goes here", "Message Goes here", $YesNoChoices, 1)
```

This will produce a similar UI that you get with  -confirm or -whatif, but you can specify the responses you want. This will work in any PowerShell Host, ISE or PowerShell.exe.

Comment: To make this easier I have created a PowerShell module [get-MultipleChoiceQuestionAnswered](https://github.com/ChrisMagnuson/get-MultipleChoiceQuestionAnswered) so that I can write something like `$Priority = get-MultipleChoiceQuestionAnswered -Question "What priority level should this request have?" -Choices 1,2,3,4`

Answer (score 2):

This is a personal answer, but for me ISE is a WorkFrame to edit, and debug your scripts. I prefer [PowerGUI](http://www.powergui.org/index.jspa) for that.

It's NOT the final PowerShell interpreter to execute your scipts. So if you want to add UI to you code you can Have a look on how to integrate Windows Forms or WPF in you scripts. It also exists some modules to help you that way.

Here is a Microsoft serie about WPF

[WPF & PowerShell – Part 1 ( Hello World & Welcome to the Week of WPF )](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/05/22/wpf-powershell-part-1-hello-world-welcome-to-the-week-of-wpf.aspx)

[WPF & PowerShell – Part 2 (Exploring WPF (and the rest of .NET) with Scripts)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/05/23/wpf-powershell-part-2-exploring-wpf-and-the-rest-of-net-with-scripts.aspx)

[WPF & PowerShell -- Part 3 (Handling Events)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/05/24/wpf-powershell-part-3-handling-events.aspx)

Have a look to WPK ([WPF PowerShell Toolkit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/10/15/introducing-the-windows-7-resource-kit-powershell-pack.aspx))

Comment: You make a good point - and I don't expect my end users to be using the ISE - but for my own testing, I use KeePass to automate a lot of the repetitive manual entry, and this will do wonders for my own ease of use.  And I'll check out those resources, thanks for the directions!